# I am newbie on Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

```
public TEntity GetSingle(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    try 
    { 
        var teste = _context.Set<TEntity>().Single(predicate); 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return _context.Set<TEntity>().Single(predicate);
}

Func<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo, bool> expressionPerfil = Perf => Perf.IdUsuario == memo.IdUsuario//And Perf.IdTipoPerfil(MaxValue) // And Perf.Name.lenght > 3;

Session.Add("Permissao",vw_usuarioPerfilAtributoRepository.GetSingle(expressionPerfil).IdTipoPerfil);
```

Simple problems of query, but in lambda I do not know good way to do "AND" + "MaxValue" + other "WHERE" all examples for only one WHERE.

Comment: consider elaborating your question a bit, the title itself, wording and code formatting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Lambda` you can simple add any condition using `&&` (For And) and `||` For(OR)

```
Func<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo, bool> expressionPerfil = Perf => 
                   Perf.IdUsuario == memo.IdUsuario  && 
                   Perf.IdTipoPerfil(MaxValue) && 
                   Perf.Name.lenght > 3;
```

Comment: Great thanks, sorry about my ignorance on this.
But _MaxValue_ will not work.

Answer (score 2):

It's regular C# code, so use the `&&` operator:

```
Func<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo, bool> expressionPerfil =
  Perf => Perf.IdUsuario == memo.IdUsuario &&
  Perf.IdTipoPerfil(MaxValue) &&
  Perf.Name.lenght > 3;
```

Note: `lenght` should probably be `length` or `Length`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your question but in where clause you can use `&&` for AND with multiple conditions. For your current statement try replacing AND with &&. ([Conditional operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173145.aspx) are same as c#)

```
Func<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo, bool> expressionPerfil =
Perf => Perf.IdUsuario == memo.IdUsuario 
                          && Perf.IdTipoPerfil(MaxValue) 
                          && Perf.Name.lenght > 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lamdas are simple inline declared functions.

The declaration goes as follows: () => { }

There is also a short form: () => ()=> { } // a lambda returning a lambda that does nothing.

Inside a lambda you can use every local variable in scope.

I don't know what exactly you are trying to do, but I hope I could help. :x

Regards Nils.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "&&" operator, just like in plain C#

```
Func<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo, bool> expressionPerfil = Perf => 
    Perf.IdUsuario == memo.IdUsuario 
    && Perf.IdTipoPerfil(MaxValue)
    && Perf.Name.lenght > 3;
```